# Allow users to change author of post

Tags: user-roles, author

I want to allow people to ghost-write for other people. This is why I've made a custom taxononomy in my custom post types called Author filled with all the author names.

Now I realize it's probably easier to just enable the admin feature of "changing the author" for "Authors".. But how exactly would I achieve this? 
I cannot find an option in wordpress to change user role options, and I don't want to use a plugin to change one simple(?) feature.

**TLDR: Enabling the 'change author dropdown' for "Author" users.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you don't want to use a plugin, but user role editor is awesome at creating custom roles and capabilities.  You can add extra capabilities to authors to change the author of a post.

Comment: I'll have a look at it, thanks! Why I prefer no-plugin: I try to have full control of everything, plugins are more security risks, no?